# Как перенести программу С++ в форму, что бы это было приложением

Tags: c++

Скачал код из интернета с формой , хотел попробовать запустить вылезает постоянно такая ошибка [image: ошибка] ,уже пробовал по разному никак не получается запустить эту форму . Подскажите пожалуйста ход действий что бы запустить форму уже готового кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там 2 файла с кодами которые открываются, как я понимаю их нужно объединять как то?

Comment: c++ builder есть установленный?

Comment: Да есть,скачал @KoVadim как то надо через него скачать?

Comment: @KoVadim выставил еще один скрин ,через с++ builder

Comment: судя по версии bpl файла там нужна достаточно старая версия C++ builder, а по скриншоту видно, что у Вас новая. Распакуйте проект, отройте файл проекта и пересоберите (а exe файл перед этим можно удалить для надежности)